# Is there a way to reschedule a meeting that I didn't set in Google apps calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

When I get invited to a meeting, I want to be able to reschedule the meeting but the calendar tells me

> You are about to make changes that will only be reflected on calendar
>   me@company.com

From my understanding, this will not send new invitations to the attendees.

This is a BIG feature that I am missing from Outlook and I can't find a way to do it.